# About RNN with variable length output vectors

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, gru

I have several thousands samples with equal number of features (5000, they are time dependent) and I would like to predict of vectors with variable length.

1) I'm beginner in RNN, and I'd like to know if there are the approaches except zero padding, when we have vector with variable length.

2) 5000 features are normal? Or it isn't suitable number of features for RNN (namely LSTM), because 5000 is too big

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is the "many to many" architecture, where you input one vector at a time and then it predicts as many vectors as you need.

[image: RNN Architectures]

*Courtesy of Andrej Karpathy*

And 5000 shouldn't be a problem for deep recurrent networks using advanced (LSTM/GRU) gates. Google WaveNet generates raw audio samples, which are much longer than 5000.

Comment: Do you mean fourth architecture?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't put my finger on this architecture. Am I right, that RNN in this case will predict also and number of blue boxes? If I'm, how can RNN 'learn' to do it?

Comment: No, the RNN can output an arbitrary amounts of "blue boxes". You just keep asking it for the next output without giving it an input (or by giving it an empty input) until the RNN gives you the "end" vector, then you stop.